# C++ STL : Including all libraries?

Tags: c++

How to include all the libraries of stl in my c++ code rather than individually including them. For example -

```
#include <queue>
#include <containers>
```

A simple way to include all of them. Please help ?

Comment: why would you do that?

Comment: If you are doing this I recommend you put them in a precompiled header.

Comment: You can't. Include them all separately. Here's a good list: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header

Comment: Close enough: https://groups.google.com/a/isocpp.org/forum/#!topic/std-proposals/6ZuMq_RkNNY

Comment: `#include <bits/stdc++.h>` is enough.

Answer (score 8):

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
```

this library includes most of STL headers (especially containers)

Comment: 1) That's not a library. 2) That header file only exists with certain C++ compilers. It is not a standard C++ header. 3) Because it is non-standard, there is no guarantee of what it includes, even if it exists.

Answer (score 7):

You can't but you can just make a list and put them in a header with a header guard ofc.

```
// C++ Full Standard Header Include
#include <cstdlib>
#include <csignal>
#include <csetjmp>
#include <cstdarg>
#include <typeinfo>
#include <typeindex>
#include <type_traits>
#include <bitset>
#include <functional>
#include <utility>
#include <ctime>
#include <chrono>
#include <cstddef>
#include <initializer_list>
#include <tuple>
#include <new>
#include <memory>
#include <scoped_allocator>
#include <climits>
#include <cfloat>
#include <cstdint>
#include <cinttypes>
#include <limits>
#include <exception>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <cassert>
#include <system_error>
#include <cerrno>
#include <cctype>
#include <cwctype>
#include <cstring>
#include <cwstring>
#include <cwchar>
#include <cuchar>
#include <string>
#include <array>
#include <vector>
#include <deque>
#include <list>
#include <forward_list>
#include <set>
#include <map>
#include <unordered_set>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <stack>
#include <queue>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <cmath>
#include <complex>
#include <valarray>
#include <random>
#include <numeric>
#include <ratio>
#include <cfenv>
#include <iosfwd>
#include <ios>
#include <istream>
#include <ostream>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <strstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <streambuf>
#include <cstdio>
#include <locale>
#include <clocale>
#include <codecvt>
#include <regex>
#include <atomic>
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>
#include <future>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <ciso646>
#include <ccomplex>
#include <ctgmath>
#include <cstdalign>
#include <cstdbool>
```

That should be the full list :) ( C++11 has to be active too )
You might want to remove the ones that are deprecated ( shouldn't be many / you will get a warning anyway ) and the ones you don't have because they're special / old / new

Comment: this might be really useful for students who still should not bother about the "what should I include" related questions

Comment: First of all: ouch, my eyes.  Secondly, libraries change over time. The STL is changing so no static list like this is ever going to be comprehensive and current (header cstdalign was deprecated in C++17 and removed in C++20, for example, and many libraries not listed here have been added since Nov 2014).  Thirdly, this "solution" is going to increase compile time and bloat the resulting executable, among other possible side-effects.  This is abjectly a bad idea.

Answer (score 1):

Preferably you should include only those header files you need because when preprocessor goes through your source file it would replace all header files with there actual contents. So , always try to minimize the use of headers in your program...

Comment: This isn't an answer but a comment.

Comment: Sometimes the best answer is "do not do that".

Comment: @MaximYegorushkin Not here. It's a legitimate task for creating a precompiled header.

Comment: @NeilKirk Question demands a way to include all libraries and intention is clearly to reduce the burden of taking care which files should be taken into account. I just felt mercy on pre-processor.

Comment: Ok that is true. Pre-processor is a tool. My brain time is a limited resource. I don't want to spend it keeping header includes up to date as I change code.

Comment: @NeilKirk Preprocessor is a tool and brain is just a resource for some expensive client which wouldn't want to keep it doing these nasty things which can cost performance bottlenecks...

Answer (score 1):

There is no way and no need to do it in most cases. If you have more than 1 c++ file you could create header file which includes everything what you need and include this single header in all your c++ files - this approach also helps to use precompiled headers.

Answer (score 1):

libstdc++ [documents](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/using_headers.html) a header file called [`stdc++.h`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.9.0/libstdc++/api/a01494_source.html) which includes most of (not all) the standard headers based on the language dialect (for example, neither libstdc++ or libc++ seem to implement `<cuchar>`). The page gives instructions on how to create a precompiled header from this.

As far as I know, libc++ doesn't have `stdc++.h`.

In Visual Studio C++, the canonical precompiled header is `stdafx.h`. You can take the contents of `stdc++.h` and copy/paste it over if you wish. You will have to modify the `#ifdef` directives which check the language dialect. In MSVC, `__cplusplus` seems to defined to something useless like `199711`. `_MSC_VER` may be of use in determining the status of C++11 features.

To use it on GCC, `#include <bits/stdc++.h>`.

Answer (score 0):

**There isn't an easy, durable way to `#include` everything.**

Even doing the obvious thing, [as has been suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26803644/11106716), doesn't really work.  The STL is updated every three years--libraries occasionally get deprecated/removed, and new ones get added all the time--and the list given in that answer is already quite obsolete.  Furthermore, even if this could be easily done it's hard to think of a situation where it would improve your code.  Including unneeded libraries bloats your executable size and, as I explain [elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73007792/11106716), slows compilation time.  It also makes your code confusing and therefore harder to maintain.

Compile time, executable size, and maintainability are coding considerations that inexperienced programmers often overlook in the rush to write code as soon as possible.  Inexperienced programmers are also sometimes intimidated by the C++ STL and don't know where to start.  I don't want to make assumptions, but I suspect your question is motivated by a combination of these two things.

If that's the case, remember that learning your away around the STL--what it provides, what it doesn't, what its limitations are, how it's organized, etc--is an important and unavoidable step to mastering any language.  Fortunately, there are lots of resources to help you.  The [Core Guidelines](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines) and the [ISOCPP FAQ](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq) are written by the language's developers (largely with new C++ users in mind) and detail the broad strokes of the language.  There are many excellent books available, too: I particularly recommend Stroustrup's [Programming: Principles and Practices Using C++](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321992784).  If you have a narrower question (about, say, what STL functions can sort iterable containers), consult [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/).  On sites like [leetcode](https://leetcode.com/) you can practice what you've learned on good programming problems.