# Does including unused headers have impact on cpp compile time?

Tags: c++, compilation, header-files

I'm working on a cpp project with many .cpp and .h files.
I've been trying to improve its slow compile time, and found cpp files in project include many unnecessary headers that are actually not used in code.

Will this deteriorate cpp compile time?

I assume it could, but I want to know exactly why it affect cpp compile time, and theoretically how much it would.

Comment: It's bound to, although precompiled headers can help. I would take them out, one .cpp file at a time as you work your way through the codebase.   Comment them out initially, find out what works and what doesn't, and then remove the ones you don't need before moving on.

Comment: _"why it affect cpp compile time"_ — Because the text in these files needs to be at least preprocessed and parsed. How much does it affect the compile time? Why don't you try it? I just created a simple source file and its compilation was 25x longer with the inclusion of few standard headers than when it was empty.

Comment: @DanielLangr Blimey!  Good of you to go to the trouble of testing this.

Comment: @DanielLangr Thanks for the tip. For your question, since the project im working on has thousands of file so i want to know the theoratical number before i try something with project.

Comment: @Lani: There is no theory, and thus no theoretical number. That is why Daniel Langr did the sensible thing, and just tested in practice - on his system. Of course, using the empty file as a baseline means that the compilation time was essentially just starting the compiler itself.

Answer (score 2):

**`#include`-ing unneeded libraries considerably slows compilation time.**

You can get a sense of why this is true from a simple experiment.  Compare the compile time of this code...

```
// no includes here!
int main() { return 0; }
```

...to this code (with several dozen `#include`s I cut/pasted from a list I found)...

```
// <dozens of useless #includes here>
int main() { return 0; }
```

...and think about what happens when you compile them.  I timed compilation of each and here's what I saw:

```
$$ time g++ no_includes.cpp -o no_includes     
g++ no_includes.cpp -o no_includes  0.04s user 0.02s system 95% cpu 0.061 total
$$ time g++ all_the_includes.cpp -o all_the_includes     
g++ all_the_includes.cpp -o all_the_includes  0.50s user 0.04s system 99% cpu 0.541 total
```

Half a second isn't very long to wait, but it's still 10 times longer than it needs to be.  And in this rather contrived example, that extra time is mainly just the time the preprocessor needed to replace each `#include` with a copy of the corresponding library.  In a more realistic scenario, where the `main()` in the second program actually made STL function calls, the compiler would need even more time to search through all the libraries for matching names, figure out which of those STL functions are viable candidates, and pick the best one.